# Непонятно условие лабораторной

Tags: c#

Написано найти максимальный и минимальный элемент это в пункте "А". В пункте "Б" тоже самое но с оговоркой использовать свойств и методов  класса System.Array. Дальше так же про прямую и обратную сортировку и заполнение четными числами нового массива. Я в мсдн смотрел класс Array но там никаких методов не нашел кроме сорт удовлетворяющим условиям моей задачи

Comment: ну так и юзайте Sort, в чем проблема-то?

Comment: а для макс мин?

Comment: я про максимуми/минимум и говорю вообще-то

Comment: ааа. понял, можно отсортировать и взять самый первый элемент, правильно?

Comment: Да, верно. Правда, ваш препод может быть имел в виду такой код:

    using System.Linq;
    
    ....
    
    var array = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    var max = array.Max();

Но если он имел в виду именно это, то мне очень жаль, у вас хреновый препод

Comment: @Dikaz: ага. хотя метод не самый эффективный, но какое задание, такое и решение.

Comment: а какой самый эффективный?

Comment: >а какой самый эффективный?

ну сами подумайте - разве нужно сортировать целый массив только чтобы найти в нем два значения? Но если в вашей методике указан именно поиск этих значений с помощью методов класса Array, то посоветовать можно только это

Comment: я неправильно прочитал оказывается(((там еще нужно вывести номер элемента а с сорт такого не получается((что делать?
Дополнение коментария) Все получилось))спасибо за поомощь)